# Duplication problem in TodoList application

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a todo-list, the following function `handleChange` gets the id of the a `todo` component and changes its attribute of `completed` from true/false. This is then saved in state of `allTodos`

```
function handleChange(id) {
        const updatedTodos = allTodos.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                todo.completed = !todo.completed
            }
            return todo
        })
    setTodos(updatedTodos)                
}
const todoComponents = allTodos.map(item => <Todos key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={handleChange}/>)
```

the function `updateDB` takes that value from state and using it to update the database.

```
function updateDB(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const value = {
        completed: false,
        text: newTodo,
        id: allTodos.length,
    }
}
```

Here's where the problem arises: `id: allTodos.length`. If one of these are deleted, it will create a todo with a duplicate ID, crashing the whole thing. I don't know how to avoid this problem.
[image]

Comment: Can't you let firebase give the todo an id?

Comment: @HMR I am not sure, I need to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

In updateDB, you are setting id to allTodos.length aka 1.